# Import a text file with Pandas as a Dataframe where columns can contain multiple words, single words, or numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was given a .txt file with 10000 rows that contain the title, imdb rating, number of votes, genres, and other information about movies. We are supposed to import this to a dataframe with pandas, but I can't figure out how to tell pandas where to separate the columns correctly. For example the first line is the movie "The Shawshank Redemption", but the second row is "Pulp Fiction". There are no commas separating the information in the .txt, only spaces. So Pandas is reading "The" "Shawshank" "Redemption" as separate fields. How am I supposed to tell Pandas how to correctly break up the .txt file? My code right now is:

```
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
labels = ['imdbID','title','year','score','votes','runtime','genres']
df = pd.read_csv('imdb_top_10000.txt', sep = ' ')
```

I am getting this error code:

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 6 fields in line 10, saw 12

Comment: Please put in the question a part of the content of the file, it can be 5 lines. This will help those who want to help you.

Comment: Plis, can you put some of the file? as example.

Comment: better show example data from file. Maybe there is some method to recognize separation. And if you generated this file then better change code in program which create this file.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong separator, the error code indicates that using your defined separator outputs more fields than expected, which then is an inconsistent format for a table.

```
import pandas as pd

labels = ['imdbID','title','year','score','votes','runtime','genres']
df = pd.read_csv('test.txt', sep = '\t', names = labels)
```

I took a quick look at a similar data file and using tab delimiters, `\t` should solve the problem for you. You can also pass your column names directly while constructing your dataframe.

It is always worthwhile to understand your data input structure beforehand.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is an entry class and I am still learning all the different ways to use Pandas and the different conditions.

Comment: If you find this useful, feel free to accept this as the answer, hope you are learning well!